# The conjugate of a complex number vs an expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, terminology, radicals

[image]

The Conjugate of the complex number $a+bi$ is $a+b(-i)$.
Therefore the conjugate of a real number $a$ is $a$.

But I have seen that the conjugate of the real number $a+b$ is $a-b$.

Shouldn't it be $a+b$?

Comment: @WillJagy Calculus workbook for dummies - by Mark Ryan.

Comment: @AngeloMark: You seem to be thinking of the term "conjugate" from the usage "The difference of squares $a^2-b^2$ factors into conjugates, $(a+b)(a-b)$." (Ah, your new edit confirms this!) ... In that context, "conjugate" is used to refer to the sign change in the *expressions* $a+b$ and $a-b$. Likewise, the process of rationalizing a denominator (or numerator) often involves "multiplying by the conjugate" (to exploit the difference-of-squares factorization in reverse). The usage "conjugate" for complex numbers is a *specialized instance* of this notion of flipping one sign.

Comment: Hmm if $\overline{a+b}=a-b$ then $2=3-1=\overline{3+1}=\overline{4}=\overline{2+2}=2-2=0$

Comment: @AngeloMark I've also seen it used  as in "*the rational conjugate of $a+b\sqrt{c}$ is $a-b\sqrt{c}$*". That's fair usage, but a good book would have it defined somewhere before it first uses it.

Comment: @AngeloMark: (Oops .. duplicating dxiv's point ...) Also note that, in some areas, one may refer to $3+\sqrt{5}$ and $3-\sqrt{5}$ as "conjugates", and these are both real numbers. The term is often just a generic descriptor for algebraic or numerical expressions related by a sign change; but, as I mentioned, with complex numbers it has a *specialized* meaning. (There are other [mathematical uses of "conjugate"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation) as well.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context, really. The term "conjugate" has uses all over mathematics. For example, one might consider $1-\sqrt{2}$ the "conjugate" of $1+\sqrt{2}$, since multiplying them gives you a rational number (in this case, an integer). In the context of the picture you sent, I think this is the meaning of "conjugate". When dealing with complex numbers, usually it's appropriate to call $a-bi$ the **complex** conjugate of $a+bi$. Of course, $\sqrt{x-5}+\sqrt{5}$ is probably not the **complex** conjugate of $\sqrt{x-5}-\sqrt{5}$.